# How to create an rxjs observable from a method

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I think I am trying to do something simple but I have had no luck in solving it. I want to create an observable that notifies its subscribers when the method of another object is called. I think an RxJS Observable is the right approach but I don't know how to create my Observable. I do not have access to modify the handle.ready function as it is in the DataLib library.

```
//Lets say I need to Observe the handle object for when it calls ready().
let handle = DataLib.getDataAsyncronously();
//sometime in the future DataLib will call handle.ready() which means that       
//the data is ready.
let myObservable = Rx.Observable.XXXXXX(handle.ready() is called);
myObservable.subscribe(()=>{
   //handle.ready() method just got called.
   //Do something now that handle.ready() has been called by DataLib.
});
```

How would I create myObservable such that subscribers are notified when handle.ready() gets called?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do.  A bin would help.  It seems like you have have the ordering incorrect.  In your code, the observable is created and subscribed regardless of what `handle` does.  It's hard for me to make a recommendation without knowing more about handle/getMyHandle.  Odds are you'll want to use a `create` method.  Alternatively, an Rx.Subject could work.  Stick `const subject = new Rx.Subject();` then inside of getMyHandle.ready() `subject.onNext('event')`

Comment: You are correct in that if I had access to modify the ready() method I could do as you suggest. However, the handle object comes from another library so I cannot modify the ready method. The only thing I know is that sometime in the future, handle.ready() will be called. When handle.ready() is called, I want to let my subscribers know that so that they can then get the data they have been waiting for. Thanks.

Comment: How many times is `handle.ready` being called? You could conceivably use a simple Promise for this.

Comment: I would be happy to use a Promise. handle.ready() is only called once. There will be many subscribers, not just one as in my example. Not sure if the Promise solution would not work if I have multiple subscribers?

Comment: It sounds like you need to attach a listening event to the function call.  I think that can only be done in JS by wrapping it inside an immediately invoked function expression. You'll want to have the async data in one observable and then the IIFE->Observable inside a .startWith operator.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just wanted to make sure there was no easy way to do this.

Comment: How do you get notified if `handle.ready()` is called? If you can attach an event listener to `handle` which gets notified about the `ready` event, you can simply turn that into an observable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to attach to handle would be to handle.ready() seems to replace it..?

Typically library APIs would be more like this

```
DataLib.handleDataAsyncronously(handler);
```

or have the shape of an event emitter (onReady()) than like this:

```
let handle = DataLib.getDataAsyncronously();
```

I will just assume your library does have an API precisely as you have described here rather than you maybe oversimplified it's API.

The implementation remains simple. Making a number of assumptions, including that the original handle.ready() still needs to be called, I would write something like this:

```
const originalHandler = handle.ready.bind(handle);
const ready$ = new Rx.Subject();
handle.ready = () => {
   originalHandler();
   ready$.onNext(true);
}

ready$
  .switchMap(Rx.Observable.from(handle.generatedValues)) // I assume this happens?
  .subscribe((handleValue) => {
   // handle.ready() method just got called.
   // Do something now that handle.ready() has been called by DataLib.
   // Or work with handleValue
});
```

If your library would at least return an event emitter, you could do something beautiful like:

```
const ready$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(handle, 'ready');
```